# How to change ZXingScannerView default appearance?

Tags: android, barcode, zxing

I am making a simple barcode reader app using ZXing library but I want to customize the style (layout) of the barcode reader

I am using ZXingScannerView which automatically generates the layout, I want to give it a border and change its position.

```
  ZXingScannerView scannerView;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        scannerView = new ZXingScannerView(this);         
        setContentView(scannerView);
  }
  ...
```

Comment: have you solved?

Comment: @c-an I switched from zxing to another library that uses Google vision barcode reader and I was able to customize the layout
Check this: https://github.com/KingsMentor/MobileVisionBarcodeScanner

Answer (score 0):

Look on this project in github [JourneyApps](https://github.com/journeyapps/zxing-android-embedded/blob/master/sample/src/main/java/example/zxing/MainActivity.java).

The sample code has `scanBarcodeCustomLayout(View view)` method.

```
    public void scanBarcodeCustomLayout(View view) {
        IntentIntegrator integrator = new IntentIntegrator(this);
        integrator.setCaptureActivity(AnyOrientationCaptureActivity.class);
        integrator.setDesiredBarcodeFormats(IntentIntegrator.ONE_D_CODE_TYPES);
        integrator.setPrompt("Scan something");
        integrator.setOrientationLocked(false);
        integrator.setBeepEnabled(false);
        integrator.initiateScan();
    }
```

There's very important line for you

```
integrator.setCaptureActivity(AnyOrientationCaptureActivity.class);
```

[That](https://github.com/journeyapps/zxing-android-embedded/blob/master/sample/src/main/java/example/zxing/AnyOrientationCaptureActivity.java) `AnyOrientationCaptureActivity class` just extends from `CaptureActivity` and has no any more code. So, It means `CaptureActivity` has default style for barcode view.

```
package example.zxing;

import com.journeyapps.barcodescanner.CaptureActivity;

/**
 * This Activity is exactly the same as CaptureActivity, but has a different orientation
 * setting in AndroidManifest.xml.
 */
public class AnyOrientationCaptureActivity extends CaptureActivity {

}
```

Now look on

```
setContentView(R.layout.zxing_capture);
```

All what you need to do is to create your own class. Copy all code from `CaptureActivity`, and set your `custom xml layout` in `setContentView()`.

And then attach`com.journeyapps.barcodescanner.DecoratedBarcodeView` as a view to the capturing of barcodes.

You can style that layout as you wish. For example, to make a border, just set padding in the root layout.

I hope that will help you.